# Every other letter

Tags: python-2.7

So, I have tried this problem for what it seems like a hundred times this week alone. 
It's filling in the blank for the following program...

You entered jackson and ville.
When these are combined, it makes jacksonville. 
Taking every other letter gives us jcsnil.

The blanks I have filled are fine, but the rest of the blanks, I can't figure out. Here they are.

```
x = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
y = raw_input("Enter another word: ")
print("You entered %s and %s." % (x,y))
combined = x + y
print("When these are combined, it makes %s." % combined)
every_other = ""
counter = 0
for __________________ :
    if ___________________ :
        every_other = every_other + letter
    ____________
print("Taking every other letter gives us %s." % every_other)
```

I just need three blanks to this program. This is basic python, so nothing too complicated or something I can match wit the twenty options. Please, I appreciate your help!

Comment: `letter` needs to, with each iteration of the loop, be a different letter from `combined`.  The `if` needs a way to tell if a given letter is to be included, so it needs to know which position from `combined` it came from.  I'd look into the function `enumerate`.

Comment: Well, I don't have any options for defining letter but all combined letters and letter in combined. Also asked the instructor and he was absolutely no help.

Comment: If you don't define `letter`, how can you use it in the line after the second blank?  Plus, it looks like the intention is for you to use `counter` to tell the position of each letter (that's what the 3rd blank is for).

Comment: So, where would I define letter? after the every_other + letter? Also, since letter isn't defined and there really isn't a way to define it in my options of filling the blank, doesn't it change the way to write the code? Because I have filled in the 3rd space with count = count + 1 (counter was suppose to be count) and I filled the 2nd space with count % 2 == 0, and then the first space with i in range(len(combined))

Comment: That would be too late, as `letter` is used in the line above it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to slice with a step value.

`In [10]: "jacksonville"[::2]
Out[10]: 'jcsnil'`

The slice notation means "take the subset starting at the beginning of the iterable, ending at the end of the iterable, selecting every second element". Remember that Python slices start by selecting the first element available in the slice.

**EDIT**: Didn't realize it had to fill in the blanks

```
for letter in combined:
  if(counter % 2) == 0:
    every_other = every_other + letter
  counter += 1
```

Since taking every other would mean you take every second letter, or every second pass through the loop, and you use counter to track how many passes you've made, you can use modulo division (%) to check when to take a letter. The base case is that 0 % 2 = 0, which lets you take the first letter. It's important to remember to always increment the counter.

A way to do this without the manual counter, which was already mentioned in comments is to use the `enumerate` function on `combined`. When given an iterable as a parameter, enumerate returns a generator which yields two values with each request, the position in the iterable, and the value of the iterable at that position.

I'm using this language, talking about iterables as index-able sequences, but it could be any generator-like object which doesn't have to have a finite, pre-defined sequence.

Comment: Thing is, I have to do it by that program, not create my own. It's a fill in the blank. But, thank you though. (:

Answer (score 0):

1. The first blank needs to define `letter` so that each time through the loop it is the letter at position `counter` in `combined`
2. The second blank needs to test for the current `letter`'s position being one that gets included
3. The last blank needs to modify `counter` for the next value of `letter` (much as the initial value of `counter` was for the first `letter`).

Comment: I got it now! I was stuck between using letter in combined or all letters combined because it didn't run write in Python. So, I followed this pattern and somehow, it worked for letter in combined when it wouldn't process with Python. Thank you so much!